# MySQL Force Index on Joined Table - When Optimizer Selects from Joined Table First

Tags: mysql, indexing, force-index

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, ...
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB USING (columnX)
JOIN tableC USING (columnY)
WHERE
    tableC.columnZ = zzz AND
    tableA.columnA = aaa
GROUP BY ...
```

When I run `EXPLAIN` on this query, it shows the query optimizer first selects from `tableC`, but for some reason it doesn't use an index, even though I have an index on `tableC.columnZ`.

How do I force the use of the `tableC.columnZ` in this query? I have tried:

```
...
JOIN tableC USING (columnY) FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (columnZ)
...
```

but this did not force the use of that index.

I also tried changing the order of the select:

```
...
FROM tableC FORCE INDEX (columnZ)
JOIN tableA USING (columnY)
JOIN tableB USING (columnX)
...
```

and this also didn't work.

Any advice on how to force the use of this index, or any other suggestions to make this query faster?

NOTE: `columnZ` is a `DATETIME` column, and the `WHERE` clause is:
`WHERE year(columnZ) = 2018`
not sure if this is the root of the cause?

Comment: maybe the problem is year(columnZ) have you tried hardcoding a date string?

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. Going to try hardcoding the date to Jan 1 of the specified year and using >=

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was nothing to do with the original question, and it was because I was using a function in the where clause.

Changing that clause from:

```
WHERE year(columnZ) = 2018
```

to:

```
WHERE columnZ >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

fixed the issue.